# Adding new site columns to my List, will result in having their Source field as blank inside the content type

Tags: 2013, development, content-type, site-column, issue-tracking

I have added an Issue tracking list to my SharePoint team site 2013. Then I wanted to add 5 extra columns to my list . So I did the following:-

1. I went to site settings.
2. Then I added 5 new site columns.
3. I went back to my list setting, I click on the “Issue” content type, and I added the 5 newly added site columns to my "Issue" content type , using the “Add from existing site or list columns” link as follow:-

[image]

4. And then these columns were added automatically inside the  Edit, Create& Display forms.

But since this is the first time I work on such a task , so I want to make sure that I did every thing correctly. Because I am not sure why the 5 newly added site columns will have their source field inside the “Issue” content type as blank , as shown in the above picture. So does this indicate that there is a problem ? or this is because I have added the 5 newly added site columns to the List content type and not inside the Content type at the site level ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Issue` Content Type is inherited from `Item` Content Type.

Now you can treat `Issue` as a child of `Item` and `Issue` will inherit all fields in `Item`. From the screen its clear that `Title` is sourced from `Item`.

Now the other columns are part of the `Issue` content type and hence the source is `Issue`.

The new site columns you created are simple columns and not content types. Site columns can be added to any content type. Once a content type gets inherited and at that time the column source will display the parent content type as the source.

What you have done so far is correct.

To prove this, you can add another site column to the list content type. And while adding don't select "Add to all Content types". And you can see it results in source as empty.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  but if i went to "site setting-->content type" and i added the site columns to the Issue content type at the site level (not at the list level), then the  5 new columns will have their source as Issue ,,, is this correct ?

Comment: Yes. It's not advisable to modify out of the box content type. Create a copy and modify that as part of testing.

Comment: why i should not modify out of the box content type ?

Comment: It will have a global effect and affects all content types that uses/inherits.

Comment: So if i want to extend an out of the box content type, i can modify the content type at the list level and do things such as; add site columns to it , rename the parent content type column names , chnage the type from Required to optional , etc.. is this correct ?